# how to exclude a piece of string using preg_replace() in php

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I have this string generated by wordpress functions in php

> *D:\wamp\www\myProject/wp-content/uploads/2015/11*

And I want to delete the part of

> *D:\wamp\www\myProject/*

And only have as result using preg_replace()

> *uploads/2015/11*

I know that this is a silly question but I'm new with wordpress and a little bit in php.

Cheers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this regular expression:

```
$path = "D:\wamp\www\myProject/wp-content/uploads/2015/11";
$the_desired_part = preg_replace("/.+?\/(wp-content.+?)/", "", $path);
echo $the_desired_part;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `str_replace()` for this.

```
$input = "D:\wamp\www\myProject/wp-content/uploads/2015/11";
$output = str_replace("D:\wamp\www\myProject/", "", $input);
```

`str_replace();` syntax: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Comment: I know that's kind of obvious but the string is generated and the characters will not be the same, for that reason I want to delete the first part with regular expressions.

Comment: if you can generate the string you can still pass _that_ string to `str_replace`